# Slow ranged for in Visual C++ 2015

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Does anybody know why a ranged for loop would execute significantly slower than a manual for loop in Visual C++ release mode with /Ox? Compiler issue, or is it something I'm overlooking? Is there any way to fix this?

Best performance (150ms execution):

```
for (int i = 0; i < collidables.size(); ++i)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < collidables.size(); ++j)
    {
        Collidable* first = collidables[i];
        Collidable* second = collidables[j];

        if (first != second && first->valid(second))
        {
            handle(first);
        }
    }
}
```

Okay performance (160ms execution):

```
for (auto first : collidables)
{
    for (auto second : collidables)
    {
        if (first != second && first->valid(second))
        {
            handle(first);
        }
    }
}
```

Bad performance (190ms execution):

```
for (auto& first : collidables)
{
    for (auto& second : collidables)
    {
        if (first != second && first->valid(second))
        {
            handle(first);
        }
    }
}
```

All three code snippets execute at the same speed (120ms) when compiled in GCC with -Ofast.

Comment: Have you tried /O2? And please, provide a [complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so everyone can copy, paste and check.

Comment: I have tried /O2. Same speed as /Ox. I'll see if I can whip up a simple example.

Comment: VS 2015 isn't finished. Is this with the release candidate (released this week)? If so, consider filing a bug report.

Comment: What type is `collidables`?

Comment: In the third version, `auto&` induces an extra level of indirection than the previous versions.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Collidables is std::vector<Collidable*>. Collidable (for the purposes of this example) is a class with two data members, integers m_x and m_y.

Comment: @AntonSavin I'm having trouble producing a minimal example (that doesn't require compiling several headers) due to the complexity of the original code (which I simplified for this post). When I threw together a simplified example the code of all three versions executed at the same speed. Since all I'm changing between tests is the loop type as seen in the original question, I can only assume there's a bug somewhere that's causing the code to compile differently depending on the surrounding code.